# Why doesn't this character put on their protective suit?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

At the end of Star Trek: Discovery 2x11 ("Perpetual Infinity"), it becomes clear that

> Gabrielle Burnham herself, not just her "red angel" suit,

is somehow linked to the time she operates from. (Why that should be the case entirely escapes me, but this is not the topic of this question.)

As a consequence, it is expected that

> she will be pulled back to said time of origin along with her suit as soon as the forcefield is lowered.

Before this happens, there is ample time for her to get into the suit again

> (as we saw her do rather quickly and spontaneously earlier in the same episode, in a flashback to the Klingon attack)

yet she doesn't, and

> the suit and her are sucked into the time vortex separately.

**Why in the world wouldn't she put on the suit?**

> Even if she doesn't end up in open space (as she did after her jump right after the Klingon attack), the time vortex appears to violently pull her in and there is nothing to suggest she would arrive any more smoothly on the other side. The suit's apparent capability to hover over the ground could save her life upon arrival.

Comment: Good question. The answer is probably just bad writing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

## The suit was damaged

After being shot by control the suit was damaged, and it's implied the time crystal inside was destroyed. Seeing as the suit is powered by the time crystal this is somewhat of a problem. So presumably this means the suit wouldn't be any better than just rag dolling onto the floor, at least she'd be able to duck and roll when she hit the ground outside of the suit.